# ASP.NET : insert data into SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, insert

My `web.config` file includes:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MedDBConnectionString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=DESKTOP-3NELORE;Initial Catalog=MedDB;User ID=sa;Password=mypassword"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />   
</connectionStrings>
```

From a page, I want to insert a field into a SQL Server table with this code:

```
SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection();

sc.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MedDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

sc.Open();

SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
com.Connection = sc;
com.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblSirketler (SirketAdi) VALUES ('" + txtSirketAdi.Text + "')";

com.ExecuteNonQuery();
sc.Close();
```

This code neither throws an error, nor does it add the value to the table. I am new to this subject. Thanks in advance for your answers

Comment: That could would either throw an exception or add a row to the table.  So you're probably looking at the wrong database or something.  BTW you should always use parameters in your SQL Queries, not paste in values from UI elements.

Comment: Are you sure that this code is being called? Have you tried debugging and stepping through to see if this gives any clues as to what is going on? Also, you have said you are new, so I will refrain from my usual caps lock when saying this, but it still warrants bold, [**you should always  use parameterised queries**](https://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/), and not concatenate your values into your SQL. It is vulnerable to malformed SQL, malicious SQL injection, it is not type safe, and cannot make use of cached query plans.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using a micro ORM such as [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) for queries like this. Dapper makes it very easy to parameterise your query to prevent SQL Injection. It's also a good idea to wrap the connection with a using statement.

The query itself looks good. I agree with the comments that if this code is being run, it should either add a row or throw an error.